# How to evaluate multivariate linear functions in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some problem with evaluating multivariate linear functions, or functions more than one variable.  Specifically, I have a function that is of this form:

```
 y = a + b*x1 + c*x2
```

`x1` and `x2` are variables. `a`, `b` and `c` are constants.  How can I use `numpy.polyval` to do this?

For example, if I had the following parameters:

```
   X=np.array([2,4])
   coef=np.arange(1,4)
```

How can I achieve what I want?  Here `X` contains the values of `x1` and `x2` and `coef` contains the constants.

Comment: Minor Note: Your question title is confusing. The title in no way reflects what you're actually trying to ask.  Your equation is **not** a polynomial, but it is a multivariate linear function.

Comment: @rayryeng Please feel free to suggest an edit!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ heh, ok I will!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to compute the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between a coefficients vector and a parameter vector added with a bias term.  In that case, `polyval` is not suitable to your task.  Instead compute the [dot product with `numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) between your coefficients and your parameters and add the bias term `a` on top of the result:

```
y = coef[0] + np.dot(X, coef[1:])
```